# Shiny feedback to user once e-mail is sent

Tags: r, shiny, messagebox, gmailr

I need some **shiny wisdom**, please. Below code works well in `shiny` `server` part; it sends an e-mail when user clicks `actionButton("mailButton", "e-mail!")` in `ui` part with a PDF report attached via `gmailr`. The only problem I have is that there is no feedback to the user whether e-mail has been sent. What I would ideally like to have is a message box mid-screen (maybe with overlay). When e-mail is sent it would tell so to the user who pressed the `input$mailButton` (and maybe the box would disappear with timeout of 15 seconds). This event approximately should correspond to the point of `print("message sent")` in the below code (this does get printed to the terminal). What would be a good way to do display user a confirmation that e-mail has indeed been sent and block inputs while sending is going on (which usually takes 4 seconds)?

```r
    # email sender ------------------------------------------------------------
     observeEvent(input$mailButton,{
        isolate( {
            
            library(gmailr)
            
            params <- list(startDate = min(dashData()$mdate), 
                           endDate = max(dashData()$mdate), 
                           dfSurvey = dashData(), 
                           onePerson = input$checkOnePt, 
                           onePersonNumber = input$patientNumber, 
                           showAvg = input$checkAvgLine, 
                           alphaAvg = alphaAvg)            
            
            toAddress <- input$emailAddr
            
            if (input$checkOnePt) {
                mailSubject <- paste("Feedback graph for ", input$patientNumber)
                mailText <- paste("Hello, please see the attached report from us for ",input$patientNumber)
            } else {
                mailSubject <- paste("Feedback graph")
                mailText <- paste("Hello, please see the attached report from us.")
            }
            
                
            library(rmarkdown)
            out <- render('hwu-weekly.Rmd',
                              params = params,
                              pdf_document(),
                              envir = new.env(parent = globalenv())
                )

            
            gm_auth_configure(path  = "credentials.json")
            gm_auth(email = TRUE, cache = ".secret")
            
            email <- gm_mime() %>%
                gm_to(toAddress) %>%
                gm_from("user.us@gmail.com") %>%
                gm_subject(mailSubject) %>%
                gm_text_body( mailText ) %>% 
                gm_attach_file(filename = "hwu-weekly.pdf")
            
            gm_send_message(email)

            print("message sent")
        })
    
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a good use case of `withProgress()` and `showNotification()`:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton('go', 'go')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$go, {
    withProgress(message = "Please Wait", {
      Sys.sleep(1)
      setProgress(0.25, detail = "1 Sec")
      Sys.sleep(1)
      setProgress(0.5, detail = "2 Sec")
      Sys.sleep(1)
      setProgress(0.75, detail = "3 Sec")
      Sys.sleep(1)
      setProgress(1, detail = "4 Sec")
   })
    showNotification("Your message here", type = "message", duration = 15)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Links to shiny documents for [notifications](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/showNotification.html) and [progress indicators](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/progress.html).

You could also use a [modal](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/modalDialog.html) for something more obvious that the user would have to close before moving on:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton('go', 'go')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$go, {
    withProgress(message = "Please Wait", {
      Sys.sleep(1)
      setProgress(0.25, detail = "1 Sec")
      Sys.sleep(1)
      setProgress(0.5, detail = "2 Sec")
      Sys.sleep(1)
      setProgress(0.75, detail = "3 Sec")
      Sys.sleep(1)
      setProgress(1, detail = "4 Sec")
   })
    showModal(modalDialog(title = 'Message', h2("Content Here")))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you that is looking very good. Just a simple one - in this context where would my routine `isolate({my mail sending commands})` need to go? I am not really experienced with Shiny.

Comment: They should go inside of withProgress({}). And you can manually use setProgress (or incProgress()) to move the progress indicator along. Here, I used Sys.sleep() as a placeholder function for the demonstration to simulate doing some calculation/function that would take some time.

Comment: Thanks, that works beautifully once I got my head around to the simple idea that I enclose everything inside my `observeEvent{}` action `withProgress{}` and then simply pepper the code with appropriate `setProgress` messages. Works great. User attention on the finish is better grasped with a subsequent `showModal` with `easyClose=TRUE`.